# Responsive Sidebar in twitter bootstrap 3.x

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hy there!
i want to get responsive sidebar in twitter bootstrap like [This](http://themes.laborator.co/xenon/)  and [This](http://www.cliptheme.com/demo/clip-two/STANDARD/#/app/dashboard) . Both the templetes are developed in twitter bootstrap. Can someone explain it with code example....

This is my code

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>nav</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-navigation navbar-fixed-top navbar-forex">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Header</a>
    </div>
        <ul class="visible-xs pull-right">
            <li style=" top: 0; position: absolute; right:30px; list-style-type: none; line-height: 50px; overflow: hidden;"   id="sidebar_menue"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right visible-xs">
            <li class="" style=" top: 5px; position: absolute; right: 70px; list-style-type: none; line-height: 50px;"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-bell"></span></a><span class="affix notification"><label for="" class="label label-success">5</label></span></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right visible-xs">
            <li style=" top: 5px; position: absolute; right: 150px; list-style-type: none; line-height: 50px;"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-cog"></span></a></li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs">
            <li style="margin-left: 100px;" id="sidebar_toggle"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></a></li>
        </ul>



        <ul class="nav navbar-nav left-menu hidden-xs" style="margin-left: 40px;">
            <li class="clearfix"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-bell"></span></a><span class="affix notification"><label for="" class="label label-success">5</label></span></li>
            <li class="clearfix"><a href=""><span class="fa fa-comments"> </span></a><span class="affix notification"><label for="" class="label label-primary">5</label></span></li>

        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right hidden-xs">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ><img src="../user.png" class="img-circle userimage" alt=""/> UserName <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right nav user-dropdown" role="menu">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="profile.php">Profile Setting</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


    <div class="col-md-12">

<div class="sidebar-main fixed">

<div class="col-md-3 sidebar-left navbar-left" id="sidebar">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>   items
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list" style="display: block;">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-users"></i> item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bank"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>   items
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list" style="display: block;">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-users"></i> item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bank"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>   items
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list" style="display: block;">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-users"></i> item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bank"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>   items
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list" style="display: block;">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-users"></i> item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bank"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>   items
                        <span class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="sub-menu-list" style="display: block;">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-users"></i> item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-bank"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

    <div class="col-md-9 main-container" id="main-container">
        <p>

            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


        </p>
    </div>

    </div>
    <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sidebar_toggle').click(function(){
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar-left-responsive');
                $('#main-container').toggleClass('main-cont-fullwidth');




            });


            $('#sidebar_menue').click(function(){
                $('.sidebar-left').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
                $('#sidebar').addClass('sidebar-left-responsive');



            });

    -
            $('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
                $(this).find("a").find('span.fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-right');
                $(this).find("a:not(.collapsed)").find('span').removeClass('fa-angle-right').addClass('fa-angle-down');
            })

            $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
                $(this).find("a:not(.collapsed)").find('span').removeClass('fa-angle-right').addClass('fa-angle-down');
            });

            $('#scrollbox3').enscroll({
                showOnHover: true,
                verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
                verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
            });
        });


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My css

```
    .navbar-navigation a
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-navigation a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.toggle-nav
{
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 150px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .toggle-nav
    {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        float: right!important;
    }
}
.userimage
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -45px;
    position: absolute;

}
.user-dropdown
{

    top: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;


}
.left-menu
{
    margin-left: 200px;
}
.left-menu li a
{

    border-color: #000000 !important;
}

.notification
{
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 7px;

}
.label-primary
{
    border: none;

    border-radius: 50%;
}
.label-success
{
    border: none;

    border-radius: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .left-menu
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;

    }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .left-menu
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;

    }
}

/*responsive navbar*/
.nav-sm
{
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-sec
{


}
.nav-sec li
{
    float: left!important;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.user-nav
{

    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    right: 20px;


}

.user-nav .user-drop
{
    width: 100%;
}
.udp li
{
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;

}
.udp li>ul>li
{
    background: #c0c0c0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;


}

/*Sidebar*/


.sidebar-left
{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #dc143c;
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width: 230px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;


}


.sidebar-left-responsive
{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #dc143c;
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width: 115px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;


}

.sidebar-main
{
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    background:#dc143c;
    z-index: 1;
}
.fixed
{
    height: 100%;
}
.panel
{
    margin-top: 200px;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;

}

.panel-body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px !important;

}

.panel-heading
{
    padding: 0px;
    background:#dc143c !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;

}

.panel-heading i
{
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
.panel-heading h4 a{
    padding: 12px 20px;
    display: block;

}

.panel-heading h4 a:active, .panel-heading h4 a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-heading h4 a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu-list {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #dc143c;;
    display: none;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu-list > li > a > i
{
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
.sub-menu-list > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 20px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sub-menu-list > li > a:hover
{
    background: #59646E !important;
    color: #ffffff7 !important;
}
.dropdown-difference
{
    margin-top: -18px;
}
.close
{
    width:115px;


}
.hide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.show
{
    visibility: visible;
}

.main-container
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    position:relative;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    transition:width margin 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:width margin 0.5s
}
.main-cont-fullwidth
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    transition:width margin 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:width margin 0.5s;
}
@media (min-width: 720px) {
    .main-container {
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 80%;
        position: relative;
        background: #c0c0c0;
        transition: width margin 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: width margin 0.5s
    }
    .main-cont-fullwidth
    {
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 120px;
        width: 90%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #c0c0c0;
        transition:width margin 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition:width margin 0.5s;
    }
}
```

The code works fine but the sidebar is not look good on small devices, i just want that the sidebar look like the above example on small devices....

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: @ganders He just provided the html, css as well as the JavaScript codes lol I think he tried the above