# Vertical dropdown menu in sidebar using BootStrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

from couple of hours I try figureout how vertical drop down works. Maybe somebody will be so nice and explain my what Iam doing wrong. 
I would like to achive vertical dropdown menu like is [here](http://bootstrapmaster.com/live/simpliq2/index.html).
When you click on eg 'UI Features' the sub menu roll down and move other elements down.

I tried couple of solutions but it still doesnt work. My dropdown appear above other elements.

Here is what I achived [Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/9YoqUZccbt)

Ps: I using Bootstrap v3.3.2

Comment: Welcome to the site. Two suggestions: You may include your code in the question (using appropriate formatting provided), and you may explain what is not working in your solution, if this is relevant.

Comment: ok, thanks for feedback ;). Next time I will do my best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bootstrap [collapse button component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Comment: @drSmith Great! If you got it working, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this question, and try the code user post in his question, the code works better, you can modify it according to your need..

1) [Responsive Sidebar in twitter bootstrap 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854899/responsive-sidebar-in-twitter-bootstrap-3-x)
2) [left sidebar in twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644086/left-sidebar-in-twitter-bootstrap)

The link 2 will also help you...